# Typo3 fe_renderTemplate error

Tags: webserver, typo3

Hi since I moved my Typo3 to another Webserver I get this error on my frontend.

> Typo3 Developer API error:
>
> The function
>
> fe_renderTemplate
>
> reported an error. Please check the arguments you passed to that
>   function in order to solve the problem.

Someone knows that problem?

My Typo version is 4.3.8

Greetings

Comment: Do you get the error message for every page you try to open? Do you call the function yourself? Which parameters do you use?

Comment: No I didn't, but I fixed it. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you should not use TYPO3 4.3 anymore because it's way outdated. If you can't upgrade quickly, please use at least the latest 4.3 version which is 4.3.14. After 4.3.8 there were 3 security releases so your installation might be insecure.

I suspect that the problem is that your new server is running a never PHP version. Your error comes from an extension called "api_macmade". Are you using the latest version of this extension? Do you still need it?

If you still need it and you are already using the latest version, please post the function of this method in your post so we can help you fix the problem.